# Update database values based on URL parameters

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok, so I am sending a link to a user with parameters in the URL like so:

`mydomain.com/home/reset-password.php?email=email@gmail.com&token=85988817a21062f92016a7065c`

The user clicks on the link and is taken to `reset-password.php`. On this page there are 3 fields:
Password
Confirm Password
Math Captcha

I want to update the database with the new password the user submits based on the parameters in the URL. The problem i'm running into is, it is not updating the database with the new password.

Here is my `reset-password.php` code:

```
function checkDataValidity(){
if(empty($_POST['password'])){ 
    throw new Exception("Please enter a password."); 
} 
}   

function updateUserPassword($dbHandler) {


try {

    $salt     = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 
    $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 
    for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++){ 
        $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
    }

    $urlEmail = isset($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : '';
    $urlToken = isset($_GET['token']) ? $_GET['token'] : '';

    $query_params = array( 
        ':password' => $password, 
        ':salt' => $salt,
        ':emptyToken' => '',
        ':user' =>  $urlEmail,
        ':token' => $urlToken
    ); 

    $dbHandler->beginTransaction();
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET password = :password, salt = :salt, recovery = :emptyToken  WHERE username = :user AND recovery = :token";
    $stmt = $dbHandler->prepare($sql); 
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    $dbHandler->commit(); 

    } catch(Exception $dbException){
        $dbHandler->rollback();
        echo 'The following error occured: <br/>'.$dbException->getMessage();
    }

    return true;
}




require("config.php"); //connects to the database
if(!empty($_POST)){
try {
    checkDataValidity();
    $updatePassword = updateUserPassword($db);
    if($updatePassword){
        $message = "Success!";
    } else {
        $message = "Please try again.";
    }
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo 'The following error occured: <br/>'.$e->getMessage();
}   
}
```

I am not receiving any errors anymore, but I know it has somethins to do with this:

```
$urlEmail = isset($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : '';
$urlToken = isset($_GET['token']) ? $_GET['token'] : '';
```

If I replace this `isset($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : ''` with the actual email address in the database, everything works fine. Same thing with `token`.

So basically what I am trying to do is `GET` the `email` and `token` parameter out of the URL and use that in my sql query as seen above. So when the user submits their new password update the existing password for that user and remove the token from the DB.

Is there something wrong with my code above to `GET` the parameters in the URL and use that in my query?

Comment: Try debugging by outputting `$_GET` with `echo "<pre>".print_r($_GET,true)."</pre>";`.

Comment: Where does your form post to, the same url including the query string? You might want to add the query variables from the link as hidden form fields so they get POSTed as well and you can use `$_POST` for everything.

Comment: On another note, the recommend way to hash passwords is with [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/password_hash).

Comment: Shouldn't `updateUserPassword($db)` be `updateUserPassword($dbHandler)` - I didn't see anything assigned to `$db`.

Comment: I get exactly what i'm looking for `Array
(
    [email] => email@gmail.com
    [token] => 85988817a21062f92016a7065c
)`

Comment: @iamthestreets Have you checked your PHP error logs?

Comment: @jeroen The form does post to the same url. I set the for to `action="reset-password.php"`.  @Fred-ii- the `$db` is in the `config.php` file.

Comment: So, why `$dbHandler` then? What's that do and what is your form's method or is that irrelevant?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm assuming `$dbHandler` is a PDO object or else you would get an error when trying to do `$dbHandler->beginTransaction();`

Comment: `$dbHandler` is just used for the function and the `$stmt = $dbHandler->prepare($sql);` , not sure the reason behind it - someone help with with the previous code and I am reusing it here.

Comment: Well, I see `$_GET` and I see `$_POST`. Wondering if your form's action is get/post, you might want to change your `$_GET`s to `$_REQUEST`. At this point, I don't know what else to say that will be of any further help.

Comment: `$_REQUEST` did not work for me either. @Fred-ii- Yes, i want to `$_Get` the parameters from the url and I want the `$_POST` of the new password.

Comment: What I don't understand is if I replace the `$_GET` with the actual values in the database for the $urlEmail and $urlToken variables it works fine. So it seems to me that it is not holding on to the `$_GET` values.

Comment: When you did what showdev recommended, did you put that in the `updateUserPassword()` function, or at the beginning of the script? If you just put it at the beginning of the script, try putting it right in the `updateUserPassword()` function to see if you get something different. If so, you are manipulating the `$_GET` array somewhere.

Comment: Just for the heck of it, try it without the functions. I'm thinking a scope issue. Or, placing `$urlEmail = isset($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : '';
$urlToken = isset($_GET['token']) ? $_GET['token'] : '';` somewhere that it's globally accessible, and/or passing those variables to one of the functions.

Comment: Plus this `require("config.php"); //connects to the database` shouldn't that be further up? I may be wrong, but it seems like you're trying to query before connection has been established. Could again be a scope issue also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the action attribute of your form. Based on your comment that is:

```
action="reset-password.php"
```

Note that there is no query string there, so when the form is posted, there will be no `$_GET` variables available.

There are 2 options to solve this:

1. Do everything via POST; you would have to add two hidden form fields with the `$_GET['email']` and the `$_GET['token']` fields when you build your form:
   `<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $_GET['email']; ?>">`
   `<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_GET['token']; ?>">`;
2. Append the query string to the url you use in the `action` attribute:
   `action="reset-password.php?email=<?php echo $_GET['email']; ?>&token=<?php echo $_GET['token']; ?>"`

**Note** that you might need to (should, really...) escape the `$_GET` variables for use in html and a query string, but php has standard functions for that.

Comment: I was in the process of writing this haha. I did not have to append the query string to the url in the action attribute and everything worked! Do I still need to escape the `$_GET`?

Comment: @iamthestreets I always escape my data according to the medium I am outputting to but to be honest for your `token` it does not seem necessary and I don't know if an e-mail address can contain characters that would invalidate html or a url.

Comment: @iamthestreets Putting in an answer to the solution you found would have been nice. You are allowed to put in an answer of your own you know. This way, anyone who was interested in your question, including myself would have seen what the problem was.

Comment: I used @jeroen's answer. The only thing he would need to do is remove point number 2 as this is not needed.